# Reg ex with . and space

Tags: php, regex

I am having problem with regular expression. When ever I type 'St. Joe', the input is stored on the backend as 'St.' only. I have a space in my regular expression, but i am not sure what is wrong.

Here's the function the input goes through.

```
function reg_sent($i){
    $reg_sent = "/[^A-Za-z0-9., '\n\r ]/";
    return preg_replace($reg_sent, '', $i);
}
```

Comment: OP has explained that the problem is not with the regex but something else.

Answer (score 2):

Your function removes all characters from the string that are not part of the character class `A-Za-z0-9., '\n\r`. So it leaves `"St. Joe"` completely unchanged.

Your problem must be arising from a different part of your program.

Comment: found the problem. will delete this post